# pyramid pattern in while loop c#

Tags: c#

I have to create a program to print pyramid pattern (1 2 33 44 555 666...) and sum the numbers.

Here is my solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, j;
    i = 1;

    int sum = 0;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j+=2)
        {

            Console.Write(i);
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        sum += i;
        i++;

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Summary: " + sum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And my output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here (wrong summary)?

Comment: Please do not [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58802520/205233) and re-post the exact same question - try to add information and improve your existing question because all comments asking for clarification are lost.

Comment: @RenéVogt only moving sum += i inside the for loop does not work, i need to sum numbers like (1 + 2 + 33 + 44 + 555 + 666 + 7777...) How to do that?

Comment: How about something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/Icvq2O

Comment: Well, `555` for example is: `(5 * 10^0) + (5 * 10^1) + (5 * 10^2)`. If only you had some kind of loop, where you could multiply something by ten and add the value of your current number whenever you would write it to the console...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an optimized and working version of your code:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int current = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j += 2)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            current = 10 * current + i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        sum += current;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Summary: " + sum);
```

The main issue is that you were only capturing the value of `i` (integer being printed) and using that to calculate the summary. As seen here, the current value is captured (for the entire line) within the nested loop and then added to the summary to give you the result you expect.

HTH

Comment: @Corak I don't think its worth the downvote. If the OP want he can adjust the inner loop back to `j += 2` and it will print exactly how he had it. The summary does work.

Comment: @jcruz could you please add details to support your solution; it doesn't have to be a book, but enough for the OP or anyone else that may have the same issue understand where they went wrong and how this solution would work.

Comment: thanks for the update. Not only do you provide a working solution, but you also describe the issue the OP was getting, this is very helpful to anyone coming across this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only made small adjustments to your code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, j;
    i = 1;

    int sum = 0;
    while (i <= 9)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            sum += i * (int)Math.Pow(10, j);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        i++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you like to extend your code to let the user pick a number you can do this:

Instead of this line:

```
while (i <= 9)
```

You can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 9:");

int maxValue = 1;
while (true)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out maxValue) || maxValue < 1 || maxValue > 9)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input! Try again:");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

while (i <= maxValue)
```

Answer (score -2):

Please find not optimized but quick solution

```
        int i, j;
        i = 1;

        int sum = 0;
        while (i < 9)
        {
            int current = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j += 2)
            {
                current = 10 * current + i;
                Console.Write(i);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            sum += current;
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Summary: " + sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why the convert, you should make it an int if its an int not a string; you're performing a mathematical operation.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - that's why this is a "non optimized" solution. It will do what OP probably wants, just not in a way it _should_ be done.

Comment: @Corak I understand, but declaring the right type has nothing to do with *optimization*, it's just wrong in whole.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - It does what it's supposed to do, so calling it "wrong in whole" is a bit harsh. -- Also, jcruz had the same idea (at first). So for a "quick and dirty" solution, it works. But has potential to be optimized.

Comment: @Corak it is wrong (the usage of string), if your dealing with numbers you don't perform mathematical operations on strings also it promotes wrong usage of data types. Also Rene mentions this in the above answer as well, it's wrong.

Comment: @Mahesh Waghmare could you please add details that support your answer, where the OP code is wrong and how this could solve the OP issue.

Comment: @Corak a question for you. What if OP was using doubles, floats etc. what do you think would happen with using a string to do these operations?

Comment: Guys I have updated answer... I have  said already it is not optimized solution thus given quick solution but i have updated as per @jcruz solution now.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - it feels like you misunderstand me. Of course using the right data type is better than working "stringly typed". It's an anti-pattern. And you make a very good point in saying it shouldn't be promoted. It's an anti-*pattern*, because it's so easy for us humans to think in strings. When we write "3" and then add another "3" to make it "33", we don't usually think "now I multiplied the first 3 by ten and added a 3" more often than not, we just *appended* a "3" to a string. Transfering that "workflow" into a program is a first step and definitely better than nothing.

Comment: It get's us to *some* working result. Learning, that it is much better to do it with an actual numeric type is the next step, but also a bit more abstract, because now we *do* need to do the calculation. -- In other words: "those who never did anything stringly typed throw the first stone."